# robots.txt: my site has over 700 pages indexed, but it will not rank at all

Tags: robots.txt

My robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /Templates/
Allow: /
```

I don't want the 'Templates' folder to be crawled.

Is the above correct?

What else may be causing my site to not rank, even though Google Webmaster Tools is giving green lights for everything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I'm not sure where it should go, this is my first time.

Answer (score 0):

Your robots.txt is fine. You could also use the following one, which has the same meaning (because `Allow` is only supported by some parsers, and by default everything is allowed anyway):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /Templates/
```

Note that `Disallow: /Templates/` blocks, for example, the following URLs:

- `http://example.com/Templates/`
- `http://example.com/Templates/foobar`
- `http://example.com/Templates/foobar/index.html`

But the following URLs are still allowed:

- `http://example.com/Templates`
- `http://example.com/Templates.html`
- `http://example.com/templates/`
- `http://example.com/templates/foobar.html`

---

> What else may be causing my site to not rank, even though Google Webmaster Tools is giving green lights for everything.

This question is offtopic here. You should try it at [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). But you’d need to give more details there.